# Recent open files in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How and in which component to display which files opened in the `richTextBox`? How can I implement the display of the last opened files in a `RichTextBox`? It is necessary that these files are displayed in the form of a list and you can click on them and see. Example in the picture.

Below is the code of the `button` - open.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1HXS.png)

```
string fileName;
    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        {
            using (SaveFileDialog svf = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                var firstLine = richTextBox1.Lines.FirstOrDefault();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstLine))
                {
                    svf.FileName = String.Join(" ", firstLine.Split(' ').Take(5));
                }
                svf.Filter = "Text Files (.rtf)|*.rtf";
                svf.Title = "Save";
                if (svf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    fileName = svf.FileName;
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
                    {
                        buttonSave.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(62, 65, 74);
                        sw.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                buttonSave.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(62, 65, 74);
                sw.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When someone opens a file, you save it to a list.  Save the list.

Comment: Any compelling reason why you need a RichTextBox control, and not a ListBox or ListView?

Comment: I'm doing a text editor and I need a RichTextBox for this. The last open files should not be displayed in the RichTextBox.

Comment: You don't need a RichTextBox for the list of recent files though.

Comment: I do not need RichTextBox for this. Maybe you did not understand my English. I updated the question.